# MySql select, get subtotal of price * qty with multi qty criteria

Tags: mysql, sum

I'm trying to get the correct ext_price (extended price) for the following criteria.

```
sales

id| sku| price_ea | qty
1   abc 5   1
2   abc 4   1
3   abc 6   1
4   abc 6   2
5   abc 5   2
```

The TRUE ext_price for all would be 37.

I'm running this query but results seem to be incorrect, with a total ext_price of 26

```
select sku, price_ea, sum(qty), sum(price_ea)*qty ext_price
from sales
group by sku, price_ea
```

And results:

```
sku| price_ea| qty | ext_price
222 4   1   4
222 5   3   10
222 6   3   12
```

What am I doing wrong? and how can you get correct results.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost near to the solution! I have created a **SQLFIDDLE** to visualize the query execution.

The query should be:

```
SELECT sku 
     , price_ea
     , SUM(qty) total_qty
     , price_ea*SUM(qty) ext_price
  FROM sales
 GROUP 
    BY sku
     , price_ea;
```

The **SQLFIDDLE** link is: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5880b/2

Comment: Glad to hear that my answer was perfect. I'd be grateful for any feedback or criticism that I can learn from or use to help me improve my answer as I see down-vote on it. @joell

Comment: It was my downvote. But perhaps I misunderstood. It appeared from the question that @joell expected a single result of '37'